# Restore SQL database to newer version

Tags: sql-server, windows

I'm using Drupal 7 on Windows and its using SQL Server 2008 RS2 (SP2).
Now, I have to move my site and new server using SQL Server 2016.

How can I restore my database to new server? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Backup the database on 2008R2, then restore it on the new server. You can change the compatibly level to the new version.

The last thing to do is to [add the logins from the old server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385700/restore-database-rights-on-restored-database-sql-2012).

---

You can't jump from SQL Server 2000 SP4 straight to SQL Server 2014. You are going to have to do this in two steps, restore the SQL 2000 database to a SQL2008R2 version, and change the compatibility level to 100, then back that up, and restore it to your new 2014 server.

See [ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) Compatibility Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017) in the documentation.

Comment: "Simply backup the database on 2008R2, then restore it on the new server. "  I get "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 8.00.2039. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 12.00.5540."